# Full body height element

Tags: css, insertafter

Is there any way to use `:after` or `:before` to insert a thin bar along the body? I want the bar to run from the top of the page to the bottom. I tried 
the `body:after` selector, but it did not work.

Comment: give us the code hr you work on

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/kvb5hb6f/21/

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Try to keep salutations and thanks out of questions — it's polite, but it makes it harder to summarize the post. I've fixed up the formatting of your post a little.